# Add Twitter.framework to Theos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, widget, jailbreak

I'm developing a notification center widget with `Theos` on my iPhone.

In `makefile` I added "Twitter" framework and in my project I added `<Twitter/Twitter.h>`.

When I compile the widget I get a "`Twitter/Twitter.h no such file or directory.`".

How can I add this framework? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##编译 ----------------------------yours-----------------------------
your_FILES = your/xxx.m

##连接 ----------------------------framework--------------------------
your_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit QuartzCore Foundation CoreFoundation CoreGraphics  MobileCoreServices

your_FRAMEWORKS = SystemConfiguration  CFNetwork

##连接 ----------------------------dylib------------------------------

your_LDFLAGS = -lxml2 -lz -licucore