# Add CoreMotion Framework With Theos

Tags: iphone, core-motion, theos

I am trying to use the CoreMotion framework and am compiling with theos on my jailbroken iphone4. I noticed in [Add Twitter.framework to Theos on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894475/add-twitter-framework-to-theos-on-iphone) that the makefile needed to be modified to include the necessary frameworks (which I have done). The error that I am getting is:

RootViewController.h:1:23: error: CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h: No such file or directory

which comes from the line: 
`#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>`

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

APPLICATION_NAME = SensorTest
SensorTest_FILES = main.m SensorTestApplication.mm RootViewController.mm
SensorTest_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit CoreGraphics CoreMotion 

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/application.mk
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks,
-mike

Comment: please vote up answer or accept answer if it helped

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer? I met the same issue.